# How can I add a namespace function to onclick in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, onclick

After discovering about Javascript namespaces, I tried to implement them but I run into a problem while trying to attach a namespace method to an element's onclick.

I used this method to wrap up my functions/methods/classes (a simplified concept, not my actual code):

```
;(function(window, undefined) {

    //my namespace
    var NS = {};

    NS.test = {
        f : function(param) {
            alert(param);
        }
    }

    NS.test.('test 2');

})(window);
```

Inside, everything works fine and "test 2" is prompted.

However, when I try to attach that function to a click event, by doing something like this:

```
<a href-"#" onclick="NS.test.f('test');">Click me!</a>
```

it doesn't work, just like it doesn't work when I call that function after the `})(window);` part.

I tried it calling it `window.NS.test.f('test');` but with no effect.

How can I make an onclick event call my function?

I could attach an event listener inside my wrapper, like I do for other html elements with no difficulty, but it would be problematic in this case since I'm generating the links with javascript and I find it easier and simpler to just add `onclick="doSomething"` for all my links, instead of creating them, then cache them and add event listeners.

Call me lazy, but in this particular case I prefer to do

```
someDiv.innerHTML = my_Generated_Html_Code_With_OnClick;
```

instead of

```
//demo code, ignore the flaws and the fact it won't work on IE
someDiv.innerHTML = my_generated_Html_code;
myLink = document.getElementById(id);
myLink.addEventListener('mousedown', NS.test.f('test'));
```

I do not use any framework nor do I wish to, since I'm trying to get a better understanding of the so-called vanilla javascript first.

I set up a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/F73K4/3/).

P.S. I must admit I didn't understand namespaces completely so if I'm doing something wrong here or applying the concept in a way I am not supposed to, I would appreciate any tips or corrections

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `NS` is declared inside and hence only exists inside the function:

```
function(window, undefined) {
    var NS = {};

    // NS exists here ...
}

// ... but not here
```

If you want to make it available to the rest of the page, then you can do:

```
function(window, undefined) {

    var NS = window.NS = {};

    // NS and window.NS exist here ...
}

// ... and window.NS exists here.
```

Comment: yes, I assumed that much. But is there any way to use it outside or do I need to rethink my code?